# Decide number of reducer in sort by statement in hive?

Tags: sorting, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

Do we have control over what data can we send to the reducer when doing a sort by - eg . if you have a data with 10 states (and data under each state) and you set the reducer to 6 and then you do a sort by on states column - then we will not get the desired result as we need 10 different files as the output with data sorted on states. So total data divided into 10 files and each file has the data of 10 states which is sorted.
Is my understanding correct here ? I know partitioning can divide the data into 10 different states into separate directory but then it will not be sorted and hence we use sort by. Please correct me if I am wrong.﻿